# Google Maps : Draw an optimized path

Tags: javascript, google-maps

So I have a table in javascript that contains longitudes and latitudes of some clients. What I wish to do is to draw a path that links them to make it easy to reach them. I tried the polyline but it seems to draw lines without respecting the main routes. Plus I want the path to be optimized, I choose the first client to visit and the program draws the rest of the path by linking with the closest ones. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes just knowing the name of something can help you find a solution. What you're asking about happens to be a classic problem in computing and mathematics called the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=traveling+salesman+problem) (TSP).

Armed with that knowledge, we can narrow down the search to [javascript google maps api traveling salesman problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+google+maps+api+traveling+salesman+problem), and it's our lucky day: the first match happens to be an open source [TSP solver for the Google Maps API](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-tsp-solver/).

Don't worry if you don't happen to have a Subversion client; you can download the [BpTspSolver.js](https://google-maps-tsp-solver.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/BpTspSolver.js) and [tsp.js](https://google-maps-tsp-solver.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tsp.js) files directly from Google Code.

There's also a [Google Group for the TSP solver](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-maps-tsp-solver) where you may find more info.

Comment: `Sometimes just knowing the name of something can help you find a solution`. Indeed :) Thank you for this great answer

Comment: You're welcome, Maroua, and thanks for the kind words. I'll be curious to hear how it works out for you, since I do a lot of mapping work but haven't tried out this particular code myself.

Comment: A working example http://gesamb-sireg.nivelbase.net/processamentos/caminhos/test02.html

Comment: Oh, that is very cool, thanks for posting it. It would be fun to comment out those `alert()` calls in the two .js files to see the page load without all the alerts. This kind of utility code shouldn't have alerts in it anyway - it should have a way to report errors back to the caller - but of course you can fix up the code any way you need it for your own purposes.